# How to use multiple valueEventListener at once in Firebase?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an app using Android with Firebase. I want to load the following data inside a single activity at once. Note that each data comes from different nodes.

- Total faculty members (parent node: Faculty)
- Total active/inactive faculty members (parent node: FacultyPerAccountStatus)
- Total pending/approved faculty membership (parent node: FacultyPerMembershipStatus)

[Sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pa5ZM.png)

Comment: There's no special requirements around using multiple listeners in Firebase. Did you try anything yet? Were there any error messages?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Please also show us what you have tried. Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.